# How to get the image which is clicked in rich text?

Tags: html, qt, qml, frontend

There is a real-time communication tool written in QML, and the message is transmitted in **html** format.

```
simple code:

Rectangle{
    width:300
    height: 300

    Rectangle{ // simple bubble

        anchors.centerIn: parent
        width: parent.width-100
        height: parent.height-100
        color:"#f0f0f0"
        radius: 10

        TextEdit {  //simple message show

            anchors.fill: parent
            readOnly: true
            selectByMouse: true
            clip: true
            text: "<!DOCTYPE html>
                    <html>
                    <head><meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\"/></head>
                        <body style=\"font-family:Geneva,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; font-size: 12px;\">
                            this is an image:
                            <img alt=\"\" src=\"file:/local/image.png\" />
                        </body>
                    </html>
                "
            textFormat: Text.RichText
        }
    }
}
```

And my question is how to get a clicked image from a **BubbleChatWidget**?

like:
[click action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0rKq7.png)

Similar question：[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25756791/how-to-give-qtextframe-or-qtextblock-a-background-image-in-qtextedit)

When I reference **Telegram** (web), I found that Telegram messages would not have words and pictures together. [link](https://web.telegram.org)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You migth parse the text beforehand, and wrap each image in a link `<a ...>...</a>`.

This will give you the possibility to use the `linkActivated(link)`-signal to register the click.

See the documentation:

- http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-textedit.html#linkActivated-signal
- http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-text.html#linkActivated-signal